# Cannot remove an item from the list

Tags: python, list

I created a function to remove items from a list.
The items to be removed are passed in as a list in the function argument.

Here is the code:

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']

def drop_data(data):
for i in a:
    if i in data:
        a.remove(i)
return a

data_r = ['one', 'two', 'three']

drop_data(data_r)
```

output:

```
['two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

Why can't i remove 'two' from the list?

Comment: You shouldn't remove items from a list you are iterating through.

Comment: You iterate past it, when you remove `one` then `two` becomes `a[0]`, and now your loop is looking at `a[1]` which then is `three` so that's removed second.

Comment: you also need to indent the code within your function